# how to implement smart templated type casting (e.g. C<int> / C<double> -> C<double>)

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
constexpr auto divide(T rhs, U lhs) { return rhs / static_cast<T>(lhs); }
```

Here divide defaults to the rhs type (which is the same default behavior we get from the compiler.

But what if we wanted to make divide smarter such that it would deduce in compile time the best type to return (i.e. the one which would not cause narrowing cast of any argument).

So divide(2, 3.0) would result in 0.6666... and so would divide(2.0, 3), but divide(2, 3) would still result in 0.

something like

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
constexpr auto divide2(T rhs, U lhs) { 
    if constexpr (is_same<U, double>::value)
        return static_cast<double>(rhs) / lhs;
    else
        return rhs / static_cast<T>(lhs); 
}
```

But more generic - I could go over each possible type, but is there a better way?

Is there some smart use of concepts or a metaprogramming method to figure out which is the wider type and choose it as the cast type? something like `max_type(T, U)`?

Comment: “ which is the same default behavior we get from the compiler.” - this is wrong. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions

Comment: `template<typename T, typename U> constexpr auto divide(T rhs, U lhs) { return rhs / lhs;}` seems to do the jobs here. :)

Comment: @Jarod42 You're correct :), I wanted to simplify my problem so it'd be more readable, to the point it lost its meaning... I was using a type wrapper and returning a type wrapper, in which case I did need the common_type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
constexpr T divide_impl(T rhs, T lhs) { return rhs /lhs; }

template<typename T, typename U> 
constexpr auto divide(T rhs, U lhs) { return divide_impl<std::common_type_t<T,U>>(rhs,lhs); }


int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, decltype( divide(2,2))> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<double, decltype( divide(2.0,2))> << "\n";
}
```

Output is

```
1
1
```

because `divide(2,2)` returns an `int` while `divide(2.0,2)` returns a `double`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KbsPbK7de)

However, ....

> Here divide defaults to the rhs type (which is the same default behavior we get from the compiler.

This is not right. See here for arithmetic conversions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion. And as mentioned in a comment, no cast is actually needed. The above is only useful in the more general case, but you wouldn't do such things for `rhs / lhs`.

Comment: Right, I was oversimplifying my problem ad-absurdom :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can `decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<U>())(rhs,lhs);`

Answer (score 3):

Using `common_type_t`, and `constexpr`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename type1_t, typename type2_t>
constexpr auto divide(const type1_t& value1, const type2_t& value2)
{
    using type_t = std::common_type_t<type1_t, type2_t>;
    return static_cast<type_t>(value1) / static_cast<type_t>(value2);
}


int main()
{
    static_assert(0.5 == divide(1.0, 2));
    static_assert(3ul == divide(10, 3ul));
    static_assert(0.5f == divide(1.0, 2.0f));
}
```

Comment: or `using type_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<U>());`